# Use of Spring oxm

Tags: spring, maven-3, xstream, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-oxm

I am new to spring. I was looking into spring-oxm's XStreamMarshaller. I was hoping to find a way to convert my objects into xml using this. The spring site tells me clearly how to do it but it still needs me to add a XStream dependency in my POM. I don't understand what the use of spring-oxm is? If i had to add the xstream dependency anyway then i can directly use xstreams toXml operation and be done with it? I would really appreciate any help I could get in understanding the use of spring-oxm.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides a higher level abstraction for you by eliminating the scaffolding code you need to write. For e.g. in case of OXM you will be working with `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` abstractions irrespective of the underlying implementations uses (XStream, JAXB, Castor, XmlBeans etc). Moreover it lets you use DI for injecting marshalling/unmarshalling services to your own services. Another advantage is consistent exception hierarchy irrespective of the underlying implementation. All these are well explained on their [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html).

If you have very simple needs and doesn't already use Spring then I suggest you stick to JAXB that comes with JDK 6.